# Check if a MySQL database is empty using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

Once a database is created how can it be checked if the database contains tables or table structure using PHP?

**Scenario:**

When the user accesses the system first time it creates a default database with no tables, then in the next step the user is supposed to import the customized database structure by uploading `.sql` file. I need to check if they have imported the database or has skipped that step by checking if the default database that was automatically created earlier has any table structure.

When I executed `mysql_list_tables(defaultDBName)` it just returns *"**Your SQL query has been executed successfully**"*, but no result set in **phpMyAdmin**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
$dbname = 'mysql_dbname';

if (!mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

from Documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

You can use `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)` instead of looping through $result..

Answer (score 3):

The use of mysql_query and mysql_list_tables is discouraged. Instead, you are advised to use mysqli functions.

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link,"SHOW TABLES [FROM db_name] [LIKE 'pattern']")) {
        // Check mysqli_num_rows($result). 0 means you do not have your table.
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you feel you will need some where clauses or something like this in future then use:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'somedbname'
```

If you are looking for particular table or tables you can use

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbname' AND table_name = 'tablename'
```

If you want more information then see what

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'somedbname'
```

returns

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `show tables` command to check what tables there are in the database. If it comes back empty, then the database is empty.